# get value of selected text on one tap in a textview

Tags: android, textview

How can i get the text selected on one tap from a textview. I want user to have cursor to modify the automatic selection. It's fine if it's easy with edittext, i can make it non-editable.
There shouldn't be any contextual menu. Though there are solutions available but it's not complete and clear. Like when to use spannable, disabling contextual menus.